# xss attck in url and appending string in html body using url

Tags: php, url, xss

In this URL there is a XSS attack:

```
www.example.com/login.php/'%22--%3E%3CsVg/onLOad=document['body']['append'](%603cACF1BD%60['repeat'](2))%3E
```

This decodes to

```
www.example.com/login.php/'"--><sVg/onLOad=document['body']['append'](`3cACF1BD`['repeat'](2))>
```

Because of this, some string is appending into the HTML body. How to prevent this so that it will not reflect into body?

I tried `strip_tags()` function to sanitize the url and it is working fine, but it is not preventing the string to append in body.

```
$url = strip_tags($site_url.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
```

Comment: You should really use htmlspecialchars() for XSS prevention, not strip_tags

Comment: @ADyson htmlspecialchars() is not working in my case, that's why I am using strip_tags().

Comment: Obviously you 're not using `htmlspecialchars()` right. `content="<?= htmlspecialchars($url) ?>"`.

Comment: `not working`...now working how, exactly? Be specific. Apparently strip_tags isn't doing what you wanted either - although again it's not precisely clear how. I just did a comparison of the outputs of each, for illustration: https://3v4l.org/6YN8e . I don't think you can fully prevent the content from being added to your HTML document. The purpose is to prevent the XSS attack from succeeding, that's all.

Comment: @ADyson thanks a lot your code works for me. I just wanted to redirect the page on the basis of xss url and it works when I use strip_tags() like this:
`$changed_url = strip_tags(urldecode($url));`